# Invoke API failed when trying to invoke AWS Lambda in Aurora Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created an AWS Lambda function that I want to call from an event trigger in my Aurora PostgreSQL database, but I'm having trouble even calling the Lambda function at all from within pgAdmin.

When I attempt to invoke the Lambda, I get this message:

```
ERROR:  invoke API failed
DETAIL:  AWS Lambda client returned 'User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/AuroraLambdaInvoker/dbc-role-mem-id-null is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:function:aws_lambda_arn_1 because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action'.
SQL state: XX000
```

But I have an IAM role (that I named AuroraLambdaInvoker) that gives the lambda:InvokeFunction permission attached to my database cluster. Here's the policy attached to that role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:function:TestLambda"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure what to do since, the error message specifically mentions the AuroraLambdaInvoker role I created but says "no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action," which is literally the only permission I have attached to that role. Is there something simple here that I'm missing for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add below permission to your Action and try ?

```
lambda:InvokeFunction
lambda:InvokeFunctionConfiguration
lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration
```

or you can try with this also

```
"lambda:*"
```

Full Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:function:TestLambda"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```